# how can i secure a php page from viewing without access

Tags: php, html

i have a php file named admin.php. It can be accessed by only X.But when i write the url like localhost/full/admin.php it can be viewed.it means if anyone knows the url he can access it.how can i provide security to this file thus it will be accessed.i am just using mysql and run it using localhost

Comment: Use Access Control Lists (ACL). check this link for a good tutorial on ACL http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/a-better-login-system/

Comment: You mean to tell me, you created an admin page without authentication?

Comment: There's a lot of stuff you need to look into - mainly it's about cookies and sessions - and how to store passwords in a hashed format. Use pre-existing code if you can, rather than rolling your own, as there are a lot of 'gotchas' with this sort of security stuff.

Answer (score 1):

you should look at the user & session management that php provides you. Look at it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). You can define users and its passwords, and authenticate them. This is the simplest method. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

ACL will be more beneficial in the long run.

you could use something like:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "https://mysite/a-page-that-sent-u-here") == true)
```

and then only allow access from a referrer page.

Or set a Session on one page, or even only allow it from your IP:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Lots of ways

Comment: Bear in mind though that this is only a low-security solution. The referrer information comes from the client, and so can be faked easily.

Comment: agreed. Its completely in-secure